# Memory error while uploading large file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i Upload file more than 3 gb it returns Memory error. How to upload this in chunk?

```
def anonfileupload(file):
    upload_url = 'https://api.anonfiles.com/upload'
    formdata = {
    'file': open(file, 'rb'),
}
    resp = requests.post(upload_url, files=formdata).json()
    if resp["status"]:
        resp_json = {
            "status": resp['status'],
            "url_short": resp["data"]["file"]["url"]["short"],
            "url_full": resp["data"]["file"]["url"]["full"],
            "metadata": resp["data"]["file"]["metadata"]
        }
        print(resp_json['url_short'])
    elif resp["error"]:
        print(resp["error"])
    else:
        print (resp["data"]["file"]["url"]["short"])
```

Comment: Are you by any chance running a 32 bit build of Python? On certain 32 bit systems (e.g. Windows in specific configurations) the virtual memory space is split 3 GB for user, 1 GB for kernel; it's literally impossible for a single 32 bit process to even allocate virtual memory that large, even if the 64 bit OS has enough RAM for it. Install a 64 bit version of Python (where the limits are exponentially higher) and that sort of issue won't arise (unless you *actually* run out of memory).

Comment: I am running it on linux. And small files uploaded without any issue but large files return out of memory issue.

Comment: Windows is an example. You're going to need to be more clear about the environment (bittedness of OS, Python, etc.). It's wholly possible this is just a limitation of the POST request; 3 GB, base64 encoded (given you're passing it raw binary data, it must be encoded for use with text-based HTTP), occupies ~4 GB. It's possible the library has some internal limit and refuses to try to send more than 4 GB of data per-request.